# Plugging a random variable into a probability function?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have attempted to "prove" some basic results in probability and I was wanting to know whether my "proofs" are sound without getting more involved than undergraduate multivariate calculus. I attempted to demonstrate that $\mathbb{E}(X + Y | Z) = \mathbb{E}(X|Z) + \mathbb{E}(Y|Z)$ as follows

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X + Y | Z) &= \sum_{i}\sum_{j} (x_i + y_j) f_{X,Y|Z}(x_i,y_j|Z) \\
&=  \sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i f_{X,Y|Z}(x_i,y_j|Z) + \sum_{i}\sum_{j} y_j f_{X,Y|Z}(x_i,y_j|Z) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(X|Z) + \mathbb{E}(Y|Z)
\end{align*}

where $X, Y$ and $Z$ are discrete random variables. I am particularly unsure about plugging a random variable into a probability mass function, should I be summing over all possible values of $Z$ instead?

Comment: What definition of $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Z)$ are you working with?

Comment: I've found these notes to explain conditional expectation very clearly: http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf

Comment: I actually haven't been given a definition in my course other than for when $Z = z$, for which $\mathbb{E}(X|Z = z) = \sum_{i} x_i f_{X|Z}(x_i,z)$. Thanks @Math1000 for those notes, however, they may be beyond undergraduate multivariate calculus. Is my working incorrect though?

Comment: @Casey : The "problem" is that the conditionnal expectation E(X|Z)  is not an easy notion. Your working is "incorrect" because you never defined what E(X|Z) is.

Comment: I agree with @Tryss. The actual definition of conditional expectation requires much more advanced tools than calculus. However, if you are conditioning on a discrete random variable, it is easier to understand; the example on page 2 of those notes is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\in\sigma(Z)$, then $1_A$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable, so by linearity of expectation and iterated expectation

\begin{align}\mathbb E[X1_A] + \mathbb E[Y1_A] &= \mathbb E[(X+Y)1_A]\\ &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[(X+Y)1_A\mid Z]]\\ &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X+Y\mid Z]1_A], \end{align}
and
\begin{align}\mathbb E[X1_A] + \mathbb E[Y1_A] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X1_A\mid Z]] + \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y1_A\mid Z]]\\ &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Z]1_A] + \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid Z]1_A].\end{align}

Hence

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X+Y\mid Z]1_A] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Z]1_A] + \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid Z]1_A], $$

and by definition of conditional expectation,

$$\mathbb E[X+Y\mid Z] = \mathbb E[X\mid Z] + \mathbb E[Y\mid Z]. $$

As @user190080 pointed out, here I used two properties of conditional expectation. The first is that if $S$ and $T$ random variables with finite mean, then
$$\mathbb E[S] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[S\mid T]].$$

This is what I meant by "iterated expectation." In the case where $S$ and $T$ are discrete random variables, this follows from

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\mathbb E[S\mid T]] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_s s\mathbb P(S=s\mid T) \right]\\
&= \sum_t\left(\sum_s s\mathbb P(S=s\mid T=t)\right)\mathbb P(T=t)\\
&= \sum_t\sum_s s \mathbb P(S=s\mid T=b)\mathbb P(T=t)\\
&= \sum_t\sum_s s \mathbb P(S=s, T=t)\\
&= \sum_s s\sum_t \mathbb P(S=s, T=t)\\
&= \sum_s s\mathbb P(S=s)\\
&= \mathbb E[S],
\end{align}
where the interchange in order of summation is justified by Fubini's theorem (as by definition of conditional expectation, $\mathbb E[|\mathbb E[S\mid T]|]<\infty$).

The second one is that if $A\in\sigma(T)$, i.e. $A=T^{-1}(\{t\})$ for some $t$ with $\mathbb P(T=t)>0$ where
$$T^{-1}(\{t\}) = \{\omega:T(\omega)=t\}, $$
then
$$\mathbb E[S1_A\mid T] = \mathbb E[S\mid T]1_A, $$
where $$1_A(\omega)= \begin{cases}1,&\omega\in A\\0,&\omega\notin A.\end{cases}$$
This follows from
$$\mathbb E[S1_A] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[S\mid T]1_A] $$
(by definition of conditional expectation).

Comment: yeah, that's definitely one way to show that. You could add the "two defining properties" of the conditional expectation for completeness. The only problem is that you are using already two other properties of the conditional expectation which the OP might not know about either...

Comment: From context it is safe to assume that $X,Y\in\mathcal L^1$.

Comment: what I meant are those two defining properties listed in your reference under 2./3. , and the properties the OP might not know about the collapsing property $E(E|\cdot))=E()$ and the measurbility $XE(\cdot|Z)=E(X\cdot|Z)$ but since your answer is already accepted, there is no cause for alarm. Maybe it's just convenient for other people who might check in and read your answer...